# SQL Query, i have join the same table but there is same value at different row

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by, sum

Under the same table, i have to find the summation of different field, so i'm using below query

```
select db.*, isnull(cb."8",0) as "8", db."PUR Total" - isnull(cb."8",0) as "9", eb.Item1, eb."PO Total"
  from 
  (select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as "8"
  from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
  where c.t_koor = 2 and c.t_kost = 3 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth - 1
  group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as cb
full outer join
    (select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as "PUR Total"
    from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN     inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
    where c.t_koor = 2 and c.t_kost = 3 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth
    group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as db
    on cb.Item = db.Item
--Production order
full outer join
    (select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as "8"
  from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
  where c.t_koor = 1 and c.t_kost = 5 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth - 1
  group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as ab
  on cb.Item = ab.Item
full outer join
(select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item1, sum( c.t_qstk )as "PO Total"
    from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
     where c.t_koor = 1 and c.t_kost = 5 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth
    group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as eb
    on cb.Item = eb.Item1
```

the sample output is

```
Department  Item    PUR Total   8   9       Item1       PO Total
EV           G00046301  25000   0   25000   NULL        NULL
EV           G00053001  10000   10000   0   G00053001   55
EV           G00251701  4500    4500    0   G00251701   220
TF           G01259901  200 0   200 NULL    NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL    0   NULL    NG707460AS  5
NULL        NULL        NULL    0   NULL    G00046301   72
NULL        NULL        NULL    0   NULL    G02280100   6
NULL        NULL        NULL    0   NULL    NG707460BS  5
```

from the output, you can see that there is two same data from different row under column Item and Item1. How to merge them?

sorry the code is quite messy, im still in learning process =="

Comment: Try using inner join instead of outer join.The non-matching rows will be eliminated

Comment: i have tried your method, but not what i was hoping for. but thank you. :D @Hp_issei

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle two sections are joining Item to Item, not Item to Item1.  Item to Item1 is only happening in the final join.  In your top select list, we have db.Item (from the second table) and eb.Item1 (from the last table).  Looking at Item `G00046301` we see that it is present in the db table but for it to find its match in the eb table we would need:

```
db.Item -> ab.Item -> eb.Item1
```

The middle table (ab) must not have a row for `G00046301`.  Because these are Full Outer Joins, we still get results when the middle links are missing but the tables on the end don't find their match.  So...

Since your selection seems to be more concerned with db and ab, you could try joining them directly like this:

```
select db.*, isnull(cb."8",0) as "8", db."PUR Total" - isnull(cb."8",0) as "9", eb.Item1, eb."PO Total"
  from 
  (select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as "8"
  from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
  where c.t_koor = 2 and c.t_kost = 3 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth - 1
  group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as cb
full outer join
    (select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as "Total"
    from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN     inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
    where c.t_koor = 2 and c.t_kost = 3 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth
    group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as db
    on cb.Item = db.Item
--Production order
full outer join
    (select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item, sum( c.t_qstk )as "8"
  from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
  where c.t_koor = 1 and c.t_kost = 5 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth - 1
  group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as ab
  on cb.Item = ab.Item
full outer join
(select b.t_dicl as Department, c.t_item as Item1, sum( c.t_qstk )as "Total"
    from inforlndb.dbo.twhinr1109980 AS c INNER JOIN inforlndb.dbo.ttcemm1129980 AS b ON  b.t_waid = c.t_cwar
     where c.t_koor = 1 and c.t_kost = 5 and month(c.t_trdt) <= @aMonth
    group by c.t_item, b.t_dicl) as eb
    on db.Item = eb.Item1
```

The only change is the last line

```
    on db.Item = eb.Item1
```

I hope this helps.